# Filter Specific Row Elements in a Range of Files

Tags: r, list, filtering

I am dealing with a group of files and want to filter specific row elements from all the files. First, I read all the files and created a large list.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

file_path <- fs::dir_ls("User/Low Carbon London/daily_dataset")

df <- file_path%>%
  map(function(path){
    read_csv(path)
  })
```

Each file is named as `block_^`, where `^` is an integer number. Each file within the `df` has columns look like this:

```
id mean max
a    1   2 
d    2   4 
f    3   6
```

I then read another file which contains information about the files, which is `info`. The data frame of `info` is shown as below:

```
id stdorToU Acorn_grouped   file
a     std     Affluent     block_1
b     std    Comfortable   block_2
c     ToU     Adversity    block_3 
d     ToU     Adversity    block_4
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           . 
n1     n2         n3       block_^
```

I filtered the `id`. Then I created a dataframe to make it as an index for matching the corresponding `id` in the files within the large list, where col `1` represents `id` from the `info` data frame.

```
info <- filter(info, stdorToU == "Std", Acorn_grouped == "Affluent")

i <- as.data.frame(info[,c(1)])
```

I am now stuck because I don't know how to convert such a large list into a data frame to match the `id` in `i` (or vice versa). Or is there a more efficient way of extracting the rows of `id` from the large list which contains a lot of files?

Comment: What does `info` consist of? Can you show few rows of couple of files and share the expected output for them so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: It seems like `df` is actually a list of dataframes. Beyond that, what exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: `info` consists of 4 columns: `id`, `stdorToU`, `Acorn_grouped`, `file`. I am trying to filter the `id` filtered from `info` in the large list. I edited my question to clarify myself better.

Comment: So you want to select the rows from *each* dataframe in `df` that match the ids listed in `i`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I thought I need to convert `df` to another format in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a list, where each element is a dataframe of matched rows from the corresponding input dataframe.

```
matched_rows_per_df <- lapply(df, function(x) x[x$id %in% i$id,])
```

If you want to then combine all these dataframes into a single dataframe you can do.

```
combined_matches <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, matched_rows_per_df))
```